# Angular 6 - Routing not happend - Mat-table row

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I don't know why my routing has not happened.

so far

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="searchResult_DS" class="mat-elevation-z8">
     <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayedColumns">
         <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" > {{element[column]}} </td>
     </ng-container>

     <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
     <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" 
       [routerLink] = "['/show-this-user-page', row.custId]" 
       (click)=highlightSelectedRow(row) [ngClass]="{ 'bg-clr': row === selectedRow }">
     </tr>
</table>
```

right now, am having a table with the list of data. whenever the user selects particular row it should navigate to the next page

```
public highlightSelectedRow(row): void
{
    this.picked = row.custId; 

    // i can able get values from here
    //do i need to add below line here.?
    //this.router.navigate(['/show-this-user-page']);
}
```

**routing.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'Here-where-am-doingStuffes',
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
    component: Here-where-am-doingStuffes
    // this page landing with my mat-table- then am doing routing on row 
  },
  {
    path: 'sample route 1',
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
    component: sample-route-1
  },
  {
    path: 'sample route 1',
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
    component: sample-route-2
  },
  {
    path: 'second-main-data',
    loadChildren: '/some-other-module/someother-data.module#SecondMainModule'
  }
];
```

**Error**

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'td'.
>   ("header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} 
>               ][routerLink] = "['/show-this-user', element.email]"> {{element[column]}} 
>              "): ng:///AdminModule/searchUser.html@35:51 Error: Template
>   parse errors: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known
>   property of 'td'. ("header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} 
>               ][routerLink] = "['/show-this-user', element.email]"> {{element[column]}} 
>              "): ng:///AdminModule/searchUser.html@35:51

could someone tell me where should I've to change my code and what else needs to be added?  it would so helpful if you share the working demo.

Comment: Usually that error indicates that you have not included a reference the Angular `RoutingModule` in the module that the control is in. Without that, the compiler doesn't know what to do with that directive.

Comment: I added ^^ to the answer with an example, hope that's cool

Comment: yeah.. am doing your changes in my local. ll, let you know :)

Comment: Seems like RoutingModule is not injected into the appModule

Comment: that and all injected already.

Comment: Ensure you import RouterModule to each module as i see some lazy loading. Have you set up <router-outlet></router-outlet> aswell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to you could keep the click listener and the following function should set the route params and navigate. Would then take of the [routerlink] from the `<tr>`

**controller**

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
  (click)=highlightSelectedRow(row) [ngClass]="{ 'bg-clr': row === selectedRow }">
</tr>
```

Ensure the path you are going to route to has been set up to accept a param like so. the `/:id` will let it accept one, change it to whatever your example needs to be. (I think this might be the issue).

```
{ path: 'home/:id', component: HomeViewComponent }
```

be sure to inject Router and import it.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class exampleRouter {

    constructor( private router: Router) {}

    public highlightSelectedRow(row): void
    {
        this.picked = row.custId;
        this.router.navigate(['show-this-user-page, this.picked']);
    }
}
```

**Template**

I think you are missing an import in your module, should include routing module like so.

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent],
  imports: [ 
    RouterModule, // important one, be sure to import
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule 
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And then in your template you should be able to have.

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" 
   [routerLink]="['show-this-user-page', row.custId]" 
   (click)=highlightSelectedRow(row) [ngClass]="{ 'bg-clr': row === selectedRow }">
</tr>
```

Comment: thanks for the heads-up.! can I keep my HTML same or should I remove that routeLink?

Comment: If its throwing you an error, take it off and you could use this solution

Comment: I tried as mention above.but am failed. navigation does not happen. but its simply showing clicked row data on my console. could pls share working demo

Comment: will have a look into it now, could you share some more info on your routes and how they are set up?

Comment: finally your solution and this [link](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html) example helps me to land particular user page

Comment: currently, am facing 404 error. in browser URL, am seeing this wrong format 
**http://localhost:4200/goTo-this-user/demo.demo1@sampleMail.com** but this format supposed to be like this correct format **http://localhost:4200/goTo-this-user?email=demo.demo1@sampleMail.com** . to acheive that am using below snippet in my target.ts file's ngOniniit()

Comment: like `ngOnInit() {   
    // let param1 = this._route.snapshot.queryParams["id"];
    console.log('param1', param1);
     this._sub = this._route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this._id = +params['id'];
      console.log('route ID =>', this._id);
    });    
  }`

Comment: how to get the correct format? so that it can resolve my issue

Answer (score 0):

*Solution for my scenario is achieved by using **queryParams** properly*

**parentFile.ts**

```
 this._router.navigate(['/goto-this-useDetail'], {queryParams: {email : this.currentlychosen}});
```

**targetFile.ts**

```
this._route.queryParams.subscribe(p => {
      this._order = p.email;
        console.log(this._order);
    })
```

How to use queryParams properly - [refere here](https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/)